# replace characters in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to export following chart to LaTex and replace my '+/-' with '±', just for the looks. Though, no matter what character I try (could also be an 'a' or anything else) it either doesn't change a bit or the column is empty. I found the code on several forums and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["3.90+/-0.04", "3.550+/-0.035", "3.250+/-0.033"],'B': [0.04175, 0.03800, 0.03490]})

df=df.replace("+/-", "±", regex=False)

print(df)

df.to_latex('232_a.txt', index=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace("+/-", "±", regex=False)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   3.90±0.04   0.04175
1   3.550±0.035     0.03800
2   3.250±0.033     0.03490
```